# Problems finding the Transfer Function of an OpAmp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

What is the quickest way to determine the transfer function

`G(s) = V_out(s)/V_in(s)`

of the circuit below?

**EDIT**: Ok, sorry for providing so little information. This is an exercise from an old exam. I do understand laplace operations, virtual ground and stuff. I could go ahead and use Kirchhoff and what not to try to find out the transfer function. **However**, the solution stated that it *"obviously*" was `G(s) = s`. This is why I asked for the quickest way because I thought some of you might also think that this was "obvious"!

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? What have you attempted so far? Do you understand laplace operators? Do you recognize this is a virtual earth input op-amp configuration? Would you be able to calaculate Vo/Vin if the components were just resistors?

Comment: A transfer function of `s` implies a differentiator. At high enough frequencies, this will indeed act as a differentiator, but the transfer function cannot be *just* `s` since that has dimensions (1/time) and the transfer function must be dimensionless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full analysis of this circuit is:

\$I_c = sCV_{in}\$

\$V_{out} = -I_c (R||sL) = -I_c \dfrac{sL}{1 + s\frac{L}{R}}\$

\$\Rightarrow  \dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = -\dfrac{s^2LC}{1 + s\frac{L}{R}}\$

For *s* large enough, this is approximately:

\$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} \approx -sRC\$

This is obvious only if you're familiar with the well known circuit that is identical to this one but without the inductor.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown any work for your homework, so it's difficult to know where you are stuck, however I'll provide some broad pointers to get you started.

Remember the assumptions one is allowed to make about Op Amps, provided that said Op Amp is ideal:

- Infinite input impedance (no current into inputs)
- Inputs are at the same voltage

So try working from the input to the output, from the first assumption above, you know that the voltage drop over the capacitor is the input voltage. What is the current equation through the capacitor?

Now think about where the current goes. Can you solve the rest?

EDIT:

Now that you have edited your question, we can address your actual concern. As I said, it is not exactly obvious, but sometimes I like to consider things in absolute extremes. Imagine a very high frequency, ideally, the capacitor will short and the inductor will act as an open circuit (again, in IDEAL cases).

In this situation, all that is left is R. However, since your load resistance is an infinite (open circuit), no current can actually flow. Therefore your voltage drop over R is 0. With this logic, at high frequencies this would seem to lead you to the conclusion that your Transfer function is simply 's'. As Olin mentioned, this conclusion doesn't appear right at lower frequencies, when the inductor will begin to dominate the resistor and the capacitor's impedance will rise because:

Zc = (1/jwC)

The current through the capacitor will never stop being a derivative of the voltage across it:

Ic(t) = C*(dv/dt)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry for the short question, I have now updated it, please have a look. I do know aobut these assumptions, but I was wondering whether there was an quicker way to see that `G(s) = s`.

Comment: @get2betuc Thanks for clearing up your actual question. I wouldn't say it's exactly obvious, but I'll explain in an edit in my answer.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense up to where you say that because there is not voltage over R, G is `s`. Could you elaborate on this? Thanks already though!

Comment: Your last paragraph makes little sense, and the conclusion that the transfer function is simply S is only valid for high frequencies where R dominates L.  At lower frequencies where L dominates R there is more going on than simply "S".  It is wrong to say the overall transfer function is just "S".

Comment: I agree @OlinLathrop, it appears there are some nuances which I'm not accounting for. I made an edit accounting for the lower frequencies.

Comment: Your new last sentence is still misleading.  The capacitor is *always* playing a role (making the gain frequency-depdendent).  The capacitor basically causes the derivative of the signal that would otherwise result.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Edit again.

Comment: I don't see how you arrive at the conclusion that the voltage across R is zero if there is an open circuit load.  In fact, there *can* be current through R due to the fact the output of the op amp is a (nearly ideal) voltage source.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Perhaps my understanding is wrong, the voltage source is dependent on the difference between the potential of the nodes?

Comment: @NickWilliams, the current through the capacitor *must* flow through the feedback network (no current into the op amp inputs).  At high enough frequencies, virtually all of the capacitor current flows through the resistor thus, there *must* be a voltage across the resistor.  If there is no load, the resistor current must then flow through the output pin.

Comment: Claiming that "*...since your load resistance is an infinite (open circuit), no current can actually flow. Therefore your voltage drop over R is 0...*" is a nonsense! The output impedance of an ideal OpAmp is zero and the mentioned current through R flows into the OpAmp output. The output voltage of such an amplifier is independent on the load itself.

Answer (score 2):

The basic formula for the gain of such a inverting amplifier circuit is G = Z<sub>2</sub>/Z<sub>1</sub>, where Z<sub>2</sub> is the feedback impedance and Z<sub>1</sub> is the input impedance.  In this case, Z<sub>1</sub> is just C, and Z<sub>2</sub> is the parallel combination of R and L.  Therefore:

gain = (R//L) / C

Carry out this equation using the full complex impedance and you get the answer.  No, I'm not going to do that since this is your homework.

Also keep in mind that the simple equation for the overall gain of a inverting opamp circuit assumes that the opamp gain is high compared to the circuit gain.  The error is usually small enough to ignore as long as the opamp open loop gain is 10x or more of the closed loop gain.  Note that opamp gain falls off with frequency.

### Added:

The basic premise stated in your edit is false.  The transfer function would be simply proportional to S if the inductor weren't there.  You can approximate it as S at high frequencies, meaning after the inductor impedance becomes large relative to R.  The transfer function is more complicated when L dominates over R.  In that case it should be obvious that a S<sup>2</sup> term would dominate since there are two separate high pass filters at work, one caused by the input capacitor and one due to the inductance in the feedback path.  The frequency slope will be 12 dB per octave in that region, not the 6 dB per octave when R dominates L.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calculating the Gain using `R//L / C` I get `-w^2 LRC / (jwL+R)`. Any idea on how this is supposedly = jw? (see my edit above)

Comment: @get2: See addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The task of finding the transfer function of the given circuit can be solved only for the non-realistic case of an **idealized** opamp (without frequency dependent open-loop gain).

For each real opamp the circuit will be dynamically **instable** (loop gain anylysis with anegative stability margin due to a feedback path with a second-order lowpass behaviour). Hence, such a circuit never will work in reality.

Comment: Before applying classical methods for solving linear circuits it is always necessary to check if linear behaviour is ensured.

Answer (score 0):

apply kcl at the negative terminal of opamp vin*(sc)=-((vout/R)+(vout/LS))
take vin/vout it will give the answer 
vin/vout=-((S^2LS)/R+LS))