# Cascading op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am learning about op amps right now and have gone through all the problems in my book.  I understand them fairly well at this point but there is one that I just don't understand.

What is throwing me off is the 20k resistor.  What do I do with it?  I understnad that the first one is a inverting op amp and that the output from it would be the ratio of the impedance from the cap to the resistor.  I also see that the second one is a non inverting and that voltage out of there would be the first output times k.  k = 1+r1/r2

But how do I handle the 20k?  I am just totally lost with it.  I don't even know where to start.

[image]

Comment: This site has a built in circuit editor

Comment: Is my circuit hard to read?

Comment: Imagine this circuit without right opamp and the two 5k resistors. Left opamp's output is now connected to Vo. Can you solve it now ? Then what does right opamp + two 5 k do ?

Comment: Can you handle it if there was one op-amp with a 20k across the capacitor? If so, how? I.e. show how you would do it.

Comment: @FakeMoustache great minds they say!!

Comment: okay well I have some doubts that it is correct but for the output of the first op amp If i just put the 20k in parallel with the cap and ignore the second op amp I get 1.788cos(1000t-63.4349)

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Well, this is more suitable for chat, but since you don't go there: did you guess/see what that 2nd opamp actually ended up doing? I certainly did not before calculating quite a bit.

Comment: It looks very familiar to me: a simple non-inverting x2 amplifier. But since it is inside the overall feedback loop, the overall gain (Vo/Vi) is the same. The 0.1 uF cap disturbes the picture a bit, at high frequencies it will limit the gain of the first stage to 1 (one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy. I'll solve it symbolically and double-check with the QsapecNG result, which I'm also using as schematic to give symbolic names and assign some arbitrary current directions.

[image]

The symbolic result there (output voltage) is

$$ V_o = E\; \frac{-R_2(R_3+R_4)}{sCR_1R_2R_4+R_1(R_3+R_4)}$$

So how do we get this by hand? Rather simple actually. First because of the virtual grounding of the fist opamp's negative input (and a current divider):

$$I_1 = \frac{E}{R_1} = I_c + I_2$$

So

$$I_2 = \frac{E}{R_1} - I_c\;\; \text{(*)}$$

Then because of the equality of voltages on the second opamp's inputs

$$ I_4 R_4  = - \frac{I_c}{sC}$$

Also, obviously \$I_3 = I_4\$ so

$$I_c = -sCR_4I_3 \;\;\text{(**)}$$

Again because of the [virtual] grounding of the first opamp's inputs and Ohm' law:

$$ V_o = (R_3+R_4) I_3  = -I_2R_2$$

Substituting in turn the values for \$I_2\$ and \$I_c\$ from (*) and (**) in the right-hand side of this latter equality, we get:

$$ (R_3+R_4) I_3  = -I_2R_2 = - R_2 (\frac{E}{R_1}-I_c) = -R_2 (\frac{E}{R_1} + sC R_4 I_3)$$

The first and last bit of this latter equality we solve for \$I_3\$ as:

$$ I_3 = \frac{-E R_2}{R_1(R_3+R_4 + sC R_2 R_4)}$$

Finally, multiplying this by \$R_3+R_4\$ gives us \$V_o\$ as desired. If you plug in the numerical values for the passives you get:

$$V_o = \frac{-E}{0.0005s+0.5}$$

For \$s=1000j\$, this gives an nice looking result (as expected for an academic problem): \$V_o = E(-1+j)\$. I think you can take it from here :)

---

And to add a bit of insight into the formula for \$V_o\$, it can be rewritten as:

$$ V_o = -E\; \frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{R_3+R_4}{R_3 + R_4 (1+sCR_2)} = -E\; \frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}}{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}+sCR_2} = \\ = -E\; \frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{sCR_2}{1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}}}$$

I don't really know what practical function this circuit might have (it seems the integration time constant gets sliced by the gain of the second opamp stage), but it's worth comparing with the formula for the [single stage] non-ideal integrator, e.g. from [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html):

[image]

I've confirmed through simulation (by sweeping a few values of R3: 0, 5K and 15K) that the last "insightful" formula for Vo I derived is indeed what this circuit does. The division of the time constant (equivalently multiplication of the corner frequency) is what the second opamp does (besides buffering). I don't quite see the point of it practice (when you can alter the time constant directly), but I guess that's why it's called an academic exercise.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate all the help.  I just messed around with it a lot more and something just clicked.  Now I am having no trouble with any of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can write node equations for two op-amps just like you do for a single op-amp. Since you still have negative feedback, there shouldn't be anything particularly weird about it.

Comment: Maybe its just that I'm not totally sure how to write the node equations fot this.

Comment: @user125621: Laplace is your friend.

Comment: Would be nice if I had learned how Laplace applies to this.  As I have not yet.

Comment: @user125621: Look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77457/problems-finding-the-transfer-function-of-an-opamp-circuit for an example. Also see my comments below EM Field's for expected result for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

Seems like that pesky cap and the second opamp with a gain of 2 upset the applecart.

[image]

Comment: I am unsure how this helps?

Comment: Well, at the very least it shows that the second opamp, with its gain of 2, makes a difference?

Comment: Yeah I can see that but how would you solve it by hand...  Actually how did you do the graph?  I would love to be able to run sims to check my answers...

Comment: @user125621: QsapecNG can probably solve this one symbolically.

Comment: @user125621:  Solve it by hand? Beats me... The schematic and the plot  are from LTspice, available free at http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/